# how to lock the message inbox with the app

Tags: android, locking, inbox

I want to create an android application in which when the user presses message inbox, my app should invoke and ask for the password .how to start any idea

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot lock other apps. You can write own mail application (or modify existing, open source ones like K9) but you are not able to influence other apps that way.

Comment: but there many apps existing the market .what about them ?

Comment: These are using platform bugs to achieve this. This is something you should not be doing as hopefuly these bugs will be fixed shortly

Comment: could you provide any sources for something like that ? or can i hide the existing message inbox (means the default one)